# Output conditions in a JS file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function that loads from the database all received items from the Steam service through the API. The table has an `is_withdraw` column, the default value is `0`. If the user clicks on the button, the `is_withdraw` value is changed to `1`.

I have a block on the site where all these items are displayed, though all from JS is displayed. It is necessary for those items for which `is_withdraw` value `1` to add a info text.

My JS file:

```
items.forEach( (item) => {
                        itemsCount++;
                        console.log(item.withdraw);
$('.invent-main').append('<div id="item" title="'+item.market_hash_name+'" data-id="'+item.assetid+'" data-price="'+item.price+'" onclick="Inventory.selectItemInventory('+item.assetid+')" class="rarity-'+item.type+'">\n' +
                            '<img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'+item.classid+'/60fx60f" class="invent-item">\n' +
                            '<div class="item-bottom">\n' +
                            ' <div class="item-bottom-l">\n' +
                            ''+item.price+'\n' +
                            ' </div>\n' +
                            ' <div class="item-bottom-r">\n' +
                            '<i class="fa fa-rub" aria-hidden="true"></i>\n' +
                            ' </div>\n' +
                            '</div>\n' +
                            '</div>');
                    });
```

And in my Controller i use:

```
        $withdraw = Item::where('is_withdraw', '=', 1)->get();
        $items[] = [
            'id' => $info['id'],
            'classid' => $item['icon_url'],
            'price' => round($price, 2),
            'type' => $type,
            'is_withdraw' => $withdraw
        ];
```

**var_dump($withdraw); exit;** show me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#570 (12) { ["id"]=> int(542) ["assetid"]=> string(11)
 "18235855825" ["market_hash_name"]=> string(29) "Divinations of the Nothl Haze" ["classid"]=> string(192) 
"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ5BhMYY49vRpiRVjVStup3tnaXVxgLAtZpYWqLTh02_b3fzJW5NCJnIGRkrmkYeqGkjwFupEkiL6Z8d-m2QeyrUdsNj30JNfDJgBoZVDW-QO9lO27m9bi607_CJYN" 
["price"]=> float(36.73) ["steamid"]=> string(17)
 "76561198044161202" ["type"]=> string(4) "card" ["bot"]=> string(1) "1"
["status"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) 
"2020-02-27 01:47:12" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-06 20:34:41" ["is_withdraw"]=> int(1) } }
```

As I understand it, I get an array as a result, and I need to get the value from the is_withdraw field for each thing, how can I do it right?

And now `console.log` say me `undefined`.

Comment: As far as I understood, you can use javascript array filter method to filter out is_withdraw field with value 1.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: console.log is undefined because you are using item.withdraw instead of item.is_withdraw

Comment: wooops, my bad. now all displayed :P but  how can I then derive the condition in JS? `if (is_withdraw == 1) {Item with 1 number} else {}` if `is_withdraw` 0, don't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change your console.log(item.withdraw) to console.log(item.is_withdraw) and see what happens.

Also the item::where() is returning the whole item model and not just one field. You will need to do something like:

item.is_withdraw.is_withdraw (or better yet in the php set the is_withdraw array value to $withdraw->is_withdraw).

```
$withdraw = Item::where('is_withdraw', '=', 1)->get();
    $items[] = [
        'id' => $info['id'],
        'classid' => $item['icon_url'],
        'price' => round($price, 2),
        'type' => $type,
        'is_withdraw' => $withdraw->is_withdraw
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = items.filter(item => item.is_withdraw == 1);
```

This will give all arrays with is_withdraw field value 1. For more, refer this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter